# In D6, how can I hide a block from users who have submitted a certain webform?

Tags: 6, webforms

I am doing a survey and have created a block to display a notification to site visitors to ask them to click a link to answer the survey. I want the notification to show up on all pages until they answer it. But once they've answered the survey, I'd like to hide it. Below is the code I am using now. What do I need to add? Thanks much! :)

Along the way, if there is a better way to set these alerts, let me know.

Cheers,

Tobias

```
<?php
drupal_set_message('<h3 style="margin:0;padding:0;"><a href="/survey">Click here</a> to complete a brief survey</h3>', 'sticky error');
?>
```

Comment: I think http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16409/any-way-to-flag-users-who-previously-submitted-a-webform-on-revisit?rq=1 answers this