# Authenticated users must be able to flag webform submissions

Tags: webforms, forms, flags, users

Authenticated users must be able to flag webform submissions.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `/admin/structure/flags/add/node` and create a flag (do not check the "global" checkbox). For "Bundles" (on the same form, check "webform").

On that same form, review any of the various other options available to define/refine the flag to be created, such as:
- Flag Access,
- Display options,
- Link type,
- Etc.

Then use the "Save Flag" button.

A few other questions that may help to get you going (which are like variations of this question):

- [Any way to flag users who previously submitted a webform on revisit?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16409/any-way-to-flag-users-who-previously-submitted-a-webform-on-revisit)
- [Adding a "processed" flag to a Drupal Webform, that admins can use to indicate whether or not they've dealt with a particular submission?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137846/adding-a-processed-flag-to-a-drupal-webform-that-admins-can-use-to-indicate-w)

**Note**: The [Webform Flag Submissions](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/Jackinloadup/1081630) sandbox is for D6 only (I'm assuming this question is about D7, is it?).

Answer (score 0):

There is a sandbox project [Webform Flag Submission](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/Jackinloadup/1081630) that you can probably use as a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reactions.

Yes, this is indeed a question for D7.

Also: I in fact can make a flag-link in a table to flag the user. But I want the authenticated users to be able to view the webform submission and make a flag-possibility on that page (the page that the user gets when he watches the webform).